# Get memory address ranges for Windows program

Tags: windows, memory

I'm trying to read the memory of a Windows program based on a pointer I find by using ModuleInfo to get the address starting point and size of the module. But that pointer points to memory outside that modules address space, is there a way to find out the program uses that section of memory without having to find a pointer to it first?

Answer (score 0):

See if the program in question has an *interface* ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing) ) that can be used to *interface* with said program. If there is no *documented interface*, attempting to tamper with that programs memory is a **bad idea**; and will most likely result in **undefined behaviour**. If this does not answer your question I suggest you edit it to specify *exactly which program this is about*.